# How to run webXR(AR) on iOS device?

Tags: ios, three.js, webxr

I tried running https://threejs.org/examples/#webxr_ar_cones example on my iPad(iOS 14.4.1).

I tried to run it in XRViewer, Chrome, and Safari but the example's AR button says "WEBXR NOT AVAILABLE".

[image]

So is it currently not possible to run webXR (AR) apps on an iOS device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the engine of all of those browsers is eventually safari and safari doesn't support WebXR at the current moment, this is the expected behavior.

There were a few attempts (maionly mozilla's https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/webxr-ios), but it is up to apple to add support for it in its core engine.